# Jquery dynamically select an item from dropdown not workingq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically select an item from a dropdown menu but it doesn't seem to be working although I've been utilizing the ways people have mentioned on this forum.

This is my html:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label requiredLabel">TITLE</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="selectedDialInSetting" id="selectedDialInSetting">
          <option value="SIP">SIP</option>
          <option value="SIPS">SIPS</option>
          <option value="H323">H323</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sipOrH323DialIn" id="sipOrH323DialIn" value="{{sipOrH323DialIn}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is how I'm attempting to change it:

```
$("#selectedDialInSetting").val("H323").change();
$("#sipOrH323DialIn").val("hello) // this gets set correctly
```

Edit: Trying to use `$('#selectedDialInSetting option[value="H323"]').prop('selected', true);` now

I would appreciate any insight!

Thanks

Comment: Just do this `$("#selectedDialInSetting").val("H323");`, no need to trigger change().

Comment: @wannadream I've tried that but it didn't seem to have an effect either

Comment: That is proved to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `$('#selectedDialInSetting option[value="H323"]').prop('selected', true);`

edit: we found the problem, the ID was being changed after page load so #selectedDialInSetting wasn't targeting correctly.

Comment: I just tested it on codepen: https://codepen.io/deskmaster/pen/qQMKQZ I would check to see if there are any javascript errors, or make sure you are including the code in the right place. Can you post the whole page?

Comment: I've updated the code but I don't see any obvious javascript errors. I'm able to correctly set the `input` after the `select` and I'm not seeing any errors in console

Comment: When are you trying to run the js to change the select? It should be set after the selection has been loaded into the DOM (i.e. in the footer or $(document).ready() or on a button click)

Comment: It's being called on after the user selects a value from another dropdown

Comment: See this codepen: https://codepen.io/deskmaster/pen/qQMKQZ I am changing the 2nd drop down when you change the first, I imagine the problem is in your event code for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184358/discussion-between-bowie-and-tim).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selectedDialInSetting").change(function(){
    $("#sipOrH323DialIn").val($("#selectedDialInSetting").val())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label requiredLabel">TITLE</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="selectedDialInSetting" id="selectedDialInSetting">
          <option value="SIP">SIP</option>
          <option value="SIPS">SIPS</option>
          <option value="H323">H323</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sipOrH323DialIn" id="sipOrH323DialIn" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```